# How to extract information in a TSV file and save it in an array in JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, csv

I'm running into a problem. If I have only tsv's file name. How can i extract all its information and save it in an array, say X, where each row in the tsv file is represented by an array, say y, where X is an array of ys.

ALso how can i do this if i don't know the headers of columns names ?

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: is this server-side javascript? Access to files is pretty limited on the client side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get file contents, store in var str
var x = str.split('\n');
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
    y = x[i].split('\t');
    x[i] = y;
}

console.debug(x);
```

For help on how to get the file contents, you'll need to specify where these files will be located (on the client machine, server, etc.).

If the files are located on the client machine, you might have a rough road ahead of you.

If the files are located on the server, you'll need to do an AJAX request to get the file contents.

Comment: Part of the question is how to extract the data from the file. A good answer should address that.

Comment: The question didn't specify where the files were located. Sure, I could have asked about that before answering, but I figured I would answer anyways. I figured I was putting in at least as much effort as the OP did, and the answer ***is*** still useful.

Comment: `console.debug` was exactly what I was lacking.

Comment: It doesn't work 100% of times. 1line of TSV can be in multiples lines of the file (using `"`)

Answer (score 5):

You're going to need to use AJAX or just pure XMLHttpRequest.

http://d3js.org/ has a built-in tsv reader that does basically exactly what you want.

The syntax is

```
d3.tsv("file.tsv", function(data) {
    // use data here
});
```

The `data` variable is an array of objects with key/value pairs where the first row in the file is read in as the keys. So, for example

```
Number Awesomeness
1      5
2      3
```

will return `[{"Number":1, "Awesomeness":5}, {"Number":2, "Awesomeness":3}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Sticking this here so I can find it next time I need it:

```
// parse_tsv(tsvstring, function (row) { do something with row })
function parse_tsv(s, f) {
  var ix_end = 0;
  for (var ix=0; ix<s.length; ix=ix_end+1) {
    ix_end = s.indexOf('\n', ix);
    if (ix_end == -1) {
      ix_end = s.length;
    }
    var row = s.substring(ix, ix_end-1).split('\t');
    f(row);
  }
}
```

It's better than the accepted answer because it doesn't force building an array of lines in memory, but rather build little arrays one by one. In situations with large TSV, this can be helpful. Of course you could still build the array with the callback if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use D3, JQuery or any another framework for this. Plain and simple JavaScript (AJAX technique):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                var arrayWithValues = xhttp.responseText.trim().split('\t');
                console.log(arrayWithValues);
        };
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/some.tsv", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning**
> Dont create it by you own or be sure to takes into account all exceptions.

Typescript code

```
import parser from "csvtojson";

/**
 * - Takes into account \t and \n inside cells
 * - Remove empty columns
 * - Remove empty rows
 * - Trim cells
 */
export async function parseSheetStringInJSON(
  tsvString: string
): Promise<Record<string, string>[]> {
  function removeEmpty(obj: Object) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, v]) => Boolean(v))
    );
  }

  const parsed: Record<string, string>[] = await new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) =>
      parser({
        flatKeys: true,
        delimiter: "\t",
        trim: true,
      })
        .fromString(tsvString ?? "")
        .then(function (result) {
          const clean = result.map((el) => removeEmpty(el));
          resolve(clean);
        })
  );

  return parsed;
}

const tsvString = prompt("Please") ??
  'Key 1\tKey 2\n1.1\t"2.1\n2.11"\n1.2\t2.2\n"1.3\t1.33"\t3.3';

parseSheetStringInJSON(tsvString).then(console.log)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library:

```
alasql('SELECT MATRIX * FROM TSV("mydata.tsv")',[],function(res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = array();
$fp = fopen('/path/to/file','r');
if (($headers = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE)
  if ($headers)
    while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
      if ($line)
        if (sizeof($line)==sizeof($headers))
          $result[] = array_combine($headers,$line);
fclose($fp);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: How is this suppose to help? This question is 4 years old and asking about JavaScript; your code is written in PHP.